# an error screen is output the first time it is launched when using .sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have implemented a list of categories and an edit button for category names with a swipe action.

The code is as follows

1. EditCategoryView2.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift


class MenuViewModel2: ObservableObject {
    private var realm: Realm
    @Published var uniqueCategories: [String] = []
    
    init() {
        do {
            realm = try Realm()
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing Realm: \(error)")
            realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "TemporaryRealm"))
        }
        loadMenus()
    }
    
    func loadMenus() {
        let menus = realm.objects(Menu.self).map { $0 }
        let categories = Set(menus.map { $0.category })
        uniqueCategories = Array(categories).sorted()
    }
    
    func deleteCategory(category: String) {
        do {
            let objectsToDelete = realm.objects(Menu.self).filter("category == %@", category)
            try realm.write {
                realm.delete(objectsToDelete)
            }
            loadMenus() // リストを更新
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting category: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}

struct EditCategoryView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MenuViewModel()
    @State private var selectedCategory: String?
    @State private var isEditingCategory = false // 新しいプロパティ
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(viewModel.uniqueCategories, id: \.self) { category in
                Text(category)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                        // 編集ボタン
                        Button {
                            print("Editing \(category)")
                            selectedCategory = category
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    isEditingCategory = true
                                }
                            
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                        }
                        .tint(.blue)
                        
                    }
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isEditingCategory) {
            if let category = selectedCategory {
                // EditCategoryFormView を表示
                EditCategoryFormView(
                    editedCategory: Binding<String>(
                        get: { category },
                        set: { selectedCategory = $0 }
                    ),
                    originalCategory: Binding<String>(
                        get: { category },
                        set: { _ in } // ここではoriginalCategoryを変更する必要はないので無視
                    ),
                    onEditCategory: {
                        viewModel.loadMenus()
                        isEditingCategory = false
                    }
                )
            } else {
                // カテゴリが選択されていない場合の処理
                Text("カテゴリが選択されていません")
            }
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EditCategoryView2()
}
```

2. EditCategoryFormView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct EditCategoryFormView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var editedCategory: String // @Bindingで渡される
    @Binding var originalCategory: String
    var onEditCategory: () -> Void
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            TextField("カテゴリ名", text: $editedCategory)
            
        }
        Button("保存") {
            updateCategory()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private func updateCategory() {
        print("更新対象のカテゴリ: \(originalCategory)")

        print("updateCategoryが呼び出されました。")
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let menusToUpdate = realm.objects(Menu.self).filter("category == %@", originalCategory)
        
        print("検索しているワード:\(originalCategory)")
        print("置換後のワード:\(editedCategory)")
        
        print("更新対象のカテゴリ数: \(menusToUpdate.count)")
        do {
            try realm.write {
                menusToUpdate.forEach { menu in
                    menu.category = editedCategory
                }
            }
            onEditCategory()
        } catch {
            print("カテゴリの更新中にエラーが発生しました: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Initial Screen
[image]

However, an error screen is output the first time it is launched because the category information has not been passed.
If I then press the edit button a second time or later, the edit screen appears correctly, but I do not know why the category was not passed the first time.

I assume that there is a mistake in the way the values are passed when using .sheet.

３. When the edit button is pressed for the first time
[image]

4. When the edit button is pressed for the second time or later
   [image]

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)` or use `.sheet(isPresented: $isEditingCategory) { [selectedCategory] in`

Comment: There are a few issues with the code and it seems like it overrides some of the fundamental ways in which Realm works. LIke calling loadMenus to refresh menus after something changes - an observer should be added that does that for you. Also, why this `let menus = realm.objects(Menu.self).map { $0 }`? No reason to make that a Swift array - just use it as a Results object. It's much more memory friendly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097719/query-mongodb-realm-array-only-at-first-index/73099257#73099257) for some reading on that topic.